# Binary arrays for cellular automata

Tags: cellular-automata

Where can I download some interesting cellular arrays for Conway's Game of Life? Arrays such as the Gosper glider gun, etc? I can find the images easily enough, but are they available somewhere in binary format? And is there an orderly library somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here.

Comment: Did you tried [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/)? It comes with a rich library of patterns.

Comment: Feel free to close. FWIW I found what I needed here: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/07/conways-game-of-life/